# GTKmm books for complete beginner? Do I need to learn GTK+ before GTKmm?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I am familiar with C++ & OOP. I really want to develop a GUI for my program running on Linux using GTKmm. However, I could not find any good book or tutorial for GTKmm.

I have never done any GUI programming before. I did read the gtkmm tutorial on GTKmm homepage http://www.gtkmm.org/en/ but I couldn't understand the way labels, widgets, boxes, etc... were arranged and how to use those classes. I got confused right at the start of chapter 4.

Therefore, **my questions are**: 
1. Does any one know **a better GTKmm tutorial** rather than the one on their homepage? 
2. Does learning **GTK+ first make learning GTKmm easier**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are focused on C++, I would stick with GTKmm and not bother with GTK+ C API for now.  It's different enough and will probably just confuse you, especially if you do not have a strong C background.

Unfortunately, the 3rd-party documentation of GTKmm is a little lacking.  Their tutorial book though I think is top-notch.  I would cut/paste, then compile their sample programs. Examining the source is the best way to learn it.  For example with Chapter 4 (Buttons), look at the example program [here](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkmm-documentation/tree/examples/book/buttons/button).

Be careful to follow the right tutorial for your version of GTK ([GTK2.4](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/) vs. [GTK3.0](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/)).  GTK3 (and GTKmm 3) was just released.

Comment: SO do you think it's a good idea for me to learn C, and then GTK+, and then GTKmm?

Comment: What kind of API do you use? GTKmm or GTK+? Should I use GTK+ for C++?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to learn the C API first.

GTKmm does a lot of convenience magic that is nice to have but it also hides some details that you should understand. A lot of newbie problems are from memory management, floating and reference counting and destruction of objects.

This book is very good for beginners

[image]

Comment: So do you think I should also learn C before learning GTK+? Is learning C for GTK+ necessary?

Comment: Gtk+ is not a programming language. It is a GUI toolkit, a library that has been written in the C programming language. SO yes, you will have to learn C to learn Gtk+. Besides understanding Gtk+ , C will help give you a good understanding of programming in general